# Is it safe to leave the Windows Administrator account active?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

After enabling the Windows default Administrator account, I set a password on it and signed out until I need it again. Is it safe to leave it in this state?

Comment: Anything that gets executed in a user account, including in the background, has the same permissions as the user.  If that user is the administrator, this creates the potential to do damage that wouldn't happen if running in a regular user account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to leave it in this state?

This is entirely up to your personal preference.  The account is disabled by default for security reasons.  It’s suggested you create new users in the User user group instead of the Administrator user group.

If it’s a security concern is entirely based on whom as access to your machine.  I personally wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: What if I've added a password to the Admin account, disabled it, but kept the Administrator folder inside the Users directory. This is to ensure my settings are saved the next time I sign into the account. Does the Administrators user folder pose any security risks?

Comment: @codefl0w It poses the same security risks as any other user profile directory.  Pleased refrain from asking follow up questions within a comment. I won’t be answering anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem, you have given the hacker one piece of information for free.

You need to A rename the administrator account, or disable the administrator account and create another account with a different name with admin privileges.

Thus any hacker who is going to do a brute force attack or etc has to figure out the username and password.

The hackers will definitely try to break into the Administrators account for obvious reason.